# get request with multiple parameters mySQL using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, get

I'm writing REST API in node js.
In my database I have two FK (user_A, user_B)

```
user_A - int (FK)
user_B - int (FK)
create_date - date
```

My GET request:

```
http://localhost:3000/chats?useridA=1&useridB=1
```

And my code:

```
app.get('/chats/:useridA/:useridB', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM Chats WHERE user_A_app_id = ? AND user_B_app_id = ?",
    [req.params.useridA, req.params.useridB], (err, rows) => {
        try 
        {
            res.send(rows);    
        } 
        catch (err) 
        {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    })
});
```

The output in postman is the entire table and not the specific row.
What's the problem in my code or in my get request?

- In general the "WHERE" statement in my code is not working with more then one parameters.

[This is the "create table Chats" in my sql file for my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FD2Y.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Chats;`.

Answer (score 0):

your GET request is using **query parameters**:

```
http://localhost:3000/chats?useridA=1&useridB=1
```

So to use it inside your nodejs code, you can access those parameters us:

```
req.query.useridA
req.query.useridB
```

So the request should be like this:

```
app.get('/chats/:useridA/:useridB', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Chats WHERE user_A_app_id =' +req.param("useridA")+ 'AND user_B_app_id =' +req.param("useridB")', (err, rows) => {
        try {
            res.send(rows);    
        } 
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    })
});
```

---

or you just call get request using **url parameters**

```
http://localhost:3000/chats/:useridA/:useridB

http://localhost:3000/chats/1/1
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not helping. The result is still the entire table and not only the specific row